# Must EXT-X-MEDIA come before EXT-X-STREAM-INF?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to play an HTTP Live Stream I found on the latest Android (Version L) and it's failing. The error Android gives is:

```
E/M3UParser(152): Undefined media group '600k' referenced in stream info.
```

Looking into it further, I realized that this specific stream is first listing all the EXT-X-STREAM-INF tags before it goes on to list the matching EXT-X-MEDIA tags. I skinned the example down a bit to illustrate:

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AUDIO="600k",BANDWIDTH=1399877,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2"
http://example.com/1.m3u8
... [and later on] ...
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="600k",URI="blah",BANDWIDTH=614400
```

Looking at Android's [source code](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/httplive/M3UParser.cpp), it appears that no mechanism was put in for Android to "look ahead" in the playlist file, and the code seems to assume that the EXT-X-MEDIA tags are supposed to be listed first.

However, I was reading the IETF draft and it doesn't seem to mention any such restriction on the ordering of these tags.

So I was wondering, is this a bug in the Android implementation? Or am I missing something?

(For the record, Apple's iOS seems to play this stream fine. Looks like they do know how to "look ahead")

Comment: Hi buddy, any update on this? Can you add the bug-tracker link here for refrence plz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in stagefright. I don't think you're missing anything and probably understand it slightly better than the team that did the Android implementation.